# Selecting UITableViewCell in editing mode doesn't show rounded checkmark on the left

Tags: uitableview, editing, multipleselection

I have a UITableViewController that toggles into its editing mode when the user presses a button in the toolbar. I want the user to select multiple cells and then put a rounded red checkmark on the left side of each selected cell. I've selected *Multiple Selection During Editing* in the table view in Storyboard and no accessory / editing accessory for my custom cell.

The problem is that I can find each tapped cell in the tableView's *indexPathsForSelectedRows*, but the red checkmark on the left of each selected cell doesn't appear. However, after leaving editing mode, each selected cell shows a checkmark accessory on the right (which I don't need anymore after finishing editing).

While editing:
[image]
After editing:
[image]

Here is what I did in code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (tableView.editing)
   {
       UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
       {
           [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
       }
       else
       {
           [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
       }
   }
}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  ...
  if (tableView.editing)
  {
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
      for (NSIndexPath *selectedIndex in [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows])
      {
          if ([selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath])
          {
             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
             break;
          }
      }
  }
  ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue, I'm trying to access the property on the left in multipleEditMode but can't find the correct property..

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes across the same issue, here is a snipped of how I've solved it. I have a toolbar button connected to an IBAction that toggles the UITableView's editing mode. When editing is enabled, the user can select rows and hit a delete button which has the number of selected rows set in its label.

```
@interface TableViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray      *selectedCellRows;      // Used to remember which cells have been selected during editing mode
}

- (IBAction)toggleEditing:(id)sender;

@end


@implementation TableViewController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GeneralReservationCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];

    // Set up the cell...
    [self configureCell:cell forTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(GeneralReservationCell *)cell forTableView:(UITableView *)tableView atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Basic layout
    cell.nameLabel.text = @"Some text";

    cell.selected = NO;
    if (tableView.editing)
    {
        for (NSIndexPath *selectedIndex in selectedCellRows)
        {
            if ([selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath])
            {
                cell.selected = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.tableView.editing)
    {
        [selectedCellRows addObject:indexPath];
        [self updateEditingToolbarButton];
    }
    else
    {
        // Do whatever you do normally when the cell gets selected
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.tableView.editing)
    {
        [selectedCellRows removeObject:indexPath];
        [self updateEditingToolbarButton];
    }
}


- (void)updateEditingToolbarButton
{
    int selectedRows = [self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows count];

    if (selectedRows == 0)
    {
        [deleteBarButton setTitle:@"delete"];
        deleteBarButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [deleteBarButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete (%d)", selectedRows]];
        deleteBarButton.enabled = YES;
    }
}


#pragma mark - IBActions

- (IBAction)toggleEditing:(id)sender
{
    if(self.tableView.editing)
    {
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [selectedCellRows removeAllObjects];
        [self showToolbarInEditingMode:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self showToolbarInEditingMode:YES];
    }
}


@end
```

Additionally, I set the *Editing Accessory* to `none` in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I already fixed the issue in another way. Out of interest, there is no way to access the checkmark property on the left? It seems like you handle it in another way too

Comment: No, I use the standard checkmark. If you want to access the view of the checkmark so you can replace it with your own, you can use `cell.accessoryView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rounded circle to be filled when the cell is checked, you need to set the cell's selectionStyle to other than none.

```
cell.selectionStyle = .blue
```

This can also be set in the interface builder.

Also you if you don't want the checkmark when not editing the tableView, you need to set the cell's accessoryType to `.none` in your `else` block.

```
if tableView.isEditing {
  ...
} else {
 cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```